# OAuth Client Authentication Methods? (Alternatives to http basic)

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

My question is regarding authentication of Oauth2.0 clients with my Oauth2.0 provider. The Oauth2.0 spec states that it recommends something more secure than simple password authentication for clients. I'm wondering what some of those mecahnisms may be? And if perhaps there is one mechanism that is accepted as "most secure" or "most sensible" to implement?

Really appreciate any help! Cheers!